# Changing the name of a program before building it to ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, caching, makefile

Recently I have been working with an open source simulator called Multi2Sim (M2S). I'm using the simulator to simulate heterogeneous processors to collect data that I'm using with my senior project that is aimed to test thew efficiency of different replacment policies with heterogeneous processors. The program is downloaded from the official site https://www.multi2sim.org.

After following the instruction, I successfully installed and ran the program on my Ubuntu 14.04 from the terminal by calling the "m2s" command. I used it to run the processors with LRU, FIFO, and Random cache replacement policies because they are the only policies M2S provides. The nature of my senior project demands that I use as many replacement policies as I can. I contacted a group of researchers who worked with M2S and were able to implement their own policies to the program. After sending an nice email inquiring about the process of implementing a policy to M2S, they nicely said that they can't tell me since their search is still ongoing.

After snooping around the M2S files that I downloaded before using "make" command, I found where the replacement policies are written in C in a file called "cache.c". I understand the overall mechanism of how the C program works now.

I don't have much knowledge with how

My question is: If I write the replacement policies to the the "cache.c" file, do I need to use the "make" command again in order for me to use them with the m2s command? or can I somehow implement the policies without having to remake the whole program? If I had to remake the program, is there a possible way to make it in a way that I will have the command in the terminal with a different name?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: There's no way we can answer your questions specifically without seeing the code and build system itself. There is no single answer that applies to all C programs as it depends on how the code authors have set up their build. But in general if you change something in the build then typing "make" again will rebuild. But if you add some files then you may or may not need to change the Makefiles (depends on how the build has been set up). And yes, you can change the output file name. Most likely need to change the Makefile to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The whole point of `make` is that it will rebuild those parts of the program which need rebuilding (in fact it is designed to rebuild *only* those parts of the program that require rebuilding).

You might also want to consider putting the program under source control (`git` is worth learning) so that when you break it (as you inevitably will whilst learning) you can easily revert your mistakes, and see exactly what you changed.